# Unable to build docker image with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I have to build a docker image with `tensorflow==2.0.0` but while issuing the build command I am getting the below error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
```

Earlier a few months ago I didn't have any issue, I have compiled the image using the same command

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y apt-utils \
    python3.6 \
    python3-pip \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    libxrender-dev \
    net-tools \
    iputils-ping \
    nano
    
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==5.4.1
numpy==1.18.1
opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.16
tensorflow==2.0.0
```

Comment: I seriously doubt if TF 2.0 is supported in Python 3.6 directly via pip

Comment: @Kris I have installed `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1` few months ago on `Python 3.6` but now there is no `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1` or `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0` or `tensorflow==2.0.0` available

Comment: Why you don't use pre-build images from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&name=2.0.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading `pip` before installing the dependencies from `requirements.txt` solves the problem

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```